# What is a benefit of having source code for ICS?

Tags: android

People are so happy the source code of Ice Cream Sandwich became available for syncing. Why is that cool?

Comment: It allows for the custom roms that exists, to update their code base to ICS, in the past they were stuck working against versions before 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means they can understand how the OS is working and if they want to modify it for their devices, they can.